# Running java app in InteliJ console mac OS X

Tags: java, macos, console, ide

Is there any way to configure InteliJ Idea to run you app in a bash console like eclipse does? I can use eclipse, and I am right now because of the console. But I prefer InteliJ

Answer (score 1):

IntelliJ has a "Terminal" window where you can run commands. If it's a Spring boot project, you can launch it with mvnw spring-boot:run

Otherwise you can run the project manually by pressing the green play button next to a main method for example. Then if you go into run settings, you can copy the command intellij executed and use that, or you can make your own script.

Hope this is what you were asking for.